# If you drop a slinky into a black hole, does it stretch out?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, black-holes, spring, tidal-effect

If so, where does the energy come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it would be stretched out due to the incredibly powerful gravitational field and tidal forces. The energy comes from the gravitational field. The potential energy gradient of the gravitational field near the black hole event horizon becomes very high, meaning the end of the slinky will rapidly gain kinetic energy and stretch till it becomes "spaghettified". It wont look like a slinky anymore but more like a stretched piece of wire (or whatever it's made of).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Would you say that it's the slinky's gravitational potential energy that is converted to spring potential energy in this process, or does something about the black hole change subtly to accommodate the energy transfer?

Comment: Understood @safesphere, but where does the energy that stretches the slinky come from?  Does the slinky slow down to accommodate the stretch, or does the black hole change somehow?